# Pre-commit hooks always fails with index.lock already exists

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

When running the hooks in the pre-commit-config.yaml the hook fix-encoding-pragma e debug-statements fails (remove the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` for example, but fails) and then i can't proceed to the commit. If i try to commit again i get the same error.

I tried adding: `bash -c 'fix-encoding-pragma --remove "$@"; git add -u'` to execute the hook and then add back the file to the staged area, but doesn't seems to work. Any solution to make the hook run and add the files back?

```
pre-commit --version
2.20.0
```

```
.pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.12.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        name: Run black on staged py files
        entry: bash -c 'black "$@"; git add -u' --
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pretty-quick
        name: Prettify staged js/ts/yml files
        language: system
        entry: bash -c "if [ -d "frontend" ]; then cd frontend; yarn pretty-quick; else echo 'Skipped'; fi"
  - repo: https://github.com/IamTheFij/docker-pre-commit
    rev: v2.1.1
    hooks:
      - id: docker-compose-check
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: check-toml
      - id: requirements-txt-fixer
      - id: fix-encoding-pragma
        entry: bash -c 'fix-encoding-pragma --remove "$@"; git add -u' -- 
      - id: debug-statements
        entry: bash -c 'debug-statements "$@"; git add -u' --
```

```
Output:
fix python encoding pragma...............................................Failed
- hook id: fix-encoding-pragma
- exit code: 128

Removed encoding pragma from xxx1.py
Removed encoding pragma from xxx2.py
Removed encoding pragma from xxx3.py
fatal: Unable to create 'xxx/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Comment: Is this “pre-commit”?: https://github.com/jish/pre-commit The tags you’ve used for pre-commit/hook are generic, not proper nouns.

Comment: @Guildenstern Thanks for the feedback, it's actually this one: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit

Answer (score 0):

The pre-commit project [doesn't allow you to modify files in the commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/532).

Note that while Git itself does allow you to do this, the Git project discourages this behaviour because it causes unexpected behaviour that the user may not know about.

Comment: It's not that it won't let you, it's just not recommended. I am aware of it and I accept the risk, I just wanted to know if there was a way to understand why there was this error and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

**your setup is not recommended** -- the framework intentionally does not give you a way to blindly accept changes and will not touch the staging area -- it always gives the user a chance to look at modifications

the errors you're encountering are due to multiple `git` processes attempting to write to the index at once.  you need to track down what those processes are and limit it to only one concurrently.  you can probably track them down by watching `ps -ef` or some such during execution but it's impossible to determine given the information supplied

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit